# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnitensorflow in java.library.path Tensorflow JVM

Tags: java, tensorflow, ubuntu, jvm, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Goal: I'm trying to build and run a gradle project that includes [TensorFlow's JVM libray](https://www.tensorflow.org/jvm). I'm currently running on fresh Ubuntu 21.10 64bit server.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnitensorflow in java.library.path: [/usr/java/packages/lib, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/jni, /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu, /usr/lib/jni, /lib, /usr/lib]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2670)
        at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:830)
        at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1873)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1738)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1345)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1157)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1133)
        at org.tensorflow.internal.c_api.global.tensorflow.<clinit>(tensorflow.java:12)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1212)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1157)
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1149)
        at org.tensorflow.NativeLibrary.load(NativeLibrary.java:48)
        at org.tensorflow.TensorFlow.<clinit>(TensorFlow.java:140)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
        at org.tensorflow.Graph.<clinit>(Graph.java:1341)
        at org.ornatebyte.Test.main(Test.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Could not find jnitensorflow in class, module, and library paths.
        at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1705)
        ... 15 more
```

What I've tried: Including Libtensorflow JNI in dependencies, adding dependencies to jar, removing the redownloading dependencies, adding and referencing local jars for dependencies, and changing different TensorFlow versions.

gradle.build

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.1.2"
}

group 'org.ornatebyte'
version '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.2'

    implementation group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-core-platform', version: '0.4.0'
    //implementation group: 'org.tensorflow', name: 'tensorflow-framework', version: '0.4.0'
    implementation 'org.tensorflow:libtensorflow_jni:1.15.0'


}


jar {
    manifest {
        attributes(
                'Main-Class': 'org.ornatebyte.Test'
        )
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Test script:

```
package org.ornatebyte;


import org.tensorflow.Graph;
import org.tensorflow.Operand;
import org.tensorflow.Session;
import org.tensorflow.op.Ops;


import org.tensorflow.types.TInt32;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try(Graph graph = new Graph()) {
            Ops tf = Ops.create(graph);

            Operand x = tf.constant(1);
            Operand y = tf.constant(5);

            Operand sum = tf.math.add(x, y);

            try(Session session = new Session(graph)){
                System.out.println("The result is:  "+((TInt32) session.runner().fetch(sum)
                        .run().get(0)).getInt());
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path"));` What does that give you? The native library must be in one of those paths
https://javabydeveloper.com/gradle-system-properties-via-command-line-step-by-step-example/

Comment: Please set the "org.bytedeco.javacpp.logger.debug" system property to "true" to get more information on the console.